# PYTHONPATH ignored?

Tags: python, startup-file

Blender 2.82a on Windows 10 - I'm trying to set th PYTHONPATH environment variable before launching Blender, but it seems that Blender's version of Python somehow has disabled the standard Python behaviour of putting paths from PYTHONPATH in sys.path at startup?  If I launch with this batch file:

```
set BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS=\\ourshare\ourscripts
set PYTHONPATH=\\ourshare\ourpackages
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\blender.exe"
```

I'd expect sys.path to contain an entry of "\\ourshare\ourpackages" and be able to import things from there, but it doesn't.  os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] *does* have the value "\\ourshare\ourpackages", so Blender doesn't seem to be deleting it from the environment it passes to its Python when it starts that up, which is why I'm wondering if they've customized their interpreter to not do the standard behaviour.

I can use a startup script in \\ourshare\ourscripts\startup to do the additions to sys.path, but if I want those available to all the startup scripts, the order of executing those is indeterminate (or at least not documented)?  It may be whatever the filesystem returns when Blender queries it?  It would be cleaner if we could use PYTHONPATH as we do with all our other Python-including DCC apps.

Comment: If you have the same x.y version of python installed that blender uses, can rename the blender python path and blender will pick up your system  or venv version.

Comment: Digging through the Blender C source code, it looks like they are initializing their Python interpreter with a global configuration variable Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag set to a value that by default is false.  This causes Python to ignore PYTHONPATH, PYTHONHOME, etc.

There is a Blender command line variable --python-use-system-env which can be set to override this.  It isn't mentioned on the current documentation page, but it shows up if you run blender --help.  I think this will solve my problems.  I'll see if I can find a place to report to documentation lapse.

Comment: It is in the advanced CLI help section somewhere.  The 2.80 doco is more up to date in some ways than others.

Comment: Looks like it was added in 2.82, but the current online docs purportedly listing all the 2.82 command line options don't reflect it (it isn't in the 2.83 dev page either).  There is a mention on a "Tips and Tricks" page.

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/Python_API
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html

Comment: I'll contact Aaron to get this included in the CLI page. The commit that introduced this change was https://developer.blender.org/rBS7c2f0074f3fe2411daa7a6e351d7cbc535246871

Comment: [The changes to the manual have been committed](https://developer.blender.org/rBM6442), might take a bit until the website is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is ignored since commit [`rBS7c2f0074f3fe2411daa7a6e351d7cbc535246871`](https://developer.blender.org/rBS7c2f0074f3fe2411daa7a6e351d7cbc535246871). It caused trouble in the past, because users have [set the `PYTHONPATH` during the installation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installation-steps) without being aware of that Blender would attempt to use the modules of this Python interpreter. If the Python version wasn't compatible, Blender wouldn't work.

The CLI argument [`--python-use-system-env`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) is now documented.

Comment: Is there some other limitation instead when it comes to the python executable? No matter what I try with `BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON` or `PYTHONHOME`, you can still notice how the built-in one was started earlier.

Comment: @mirh It should work properly. Hard to say what went wrong based on your description.

Comment: Set the two aforementioned variables to whatever python *altinstall* you may have on your system (and even override `PYTHONPATH` just for peace of mind). Rather than seeing my alternative executable being run (as can be noticed by the "build date", or the "installation-dependent default" entries in sys.path), it seems like the most I can get is `PYTHONHOME` to be appended to the standard python binary. But no way to actually start another one (which afaik is what BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON should do?).

Comment: @mirh I will have to test this and report back if I've found any issue.

Comment: My very remote guess is that BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON isn't working (for some reason.. or at least the variable and parameter never seemed to make a difference for me). Assuming I'm understanding right its purpose should be "pointing to your desidered python executable".

Comment: @mirh I asked the other developers and on Windows the separate interpreter executable is only there for convenience. The actual Python interpreter is part of Blenders executable and cannot be altered by setting the environment variables. You can change e.g. site-packages through them though.

Comment: Putting aside that I don't see why that should be the case, unfortunately I'm on linux.

Comment: @mirh The same applies to Linux, the Python interpreter is part of Blender's binary and can't be replaced (unless of course you compile Blender yourself). [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is for setting the search path for modules files, [`PYTHONHOME`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) is for the search path for Python libraries and  `BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON` is for the Python libraries as well (just specifically for Blender). May I ask why you're trying to replace the interpreter?

Comment: The meaning of `BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON` is documented in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#environment-variables): *"Directory for system Python libraries"*.

Comment: Duh, spelled like that I'd argue it's quite misleading. Anyway I was trying to replace the interpreter because (*of course*) plugins. One I use once in a while has a library that depends on python 3.7, but many distros are already shipping and compiling blender with 3.8. But well, guess what, I just discovered that at the end of the day you can use `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so` and everything sticks up together magically.